# Am I trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to learn about [Docker](https://www.docker.com/), but I keep getting cryptic (to me) error messages.

Possibly the simplest example of this is trying to print the version of Docker I installed:

```
$ sudo docker version
Client version: 1.4.1
Client API version: 1.16
Go version (client): go1.3.3
Git commit (client): 5bc2ff8
OS/Arch (client): darwin/amd64
FATA[0000] Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.16/version:
    dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory.
    Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
```

I've just been going through the [user guide](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/) and following every step exactly, so I'm surprised that I get this message... What should I do now?

I just noticed that if I don't use `sudo` I don't get the error:

```
$ docker version
Client version: 1.4.1
Client API version: 1.16
Go version (client): go1.3.3
Git commit (client): 5bc2ff8
OS/Arch (client): darwin/amd64
Server version: 1.4.1
Server API version: 1.16
Go version (server): go1.3.3
Git commit (server): 5bc2ff8
```

Of course, this is not a solution as I may need to use `sudo` somewhere down the road...

I just found [another page](http://docs.docker.com/articles/basics/) saying "**If you're using OS X** then you shouldn't use `sudo`." I don't know if they mean only for that example, or in general.

Comment: Stupid question but have you started the docker daemon?

Comment: I have been following the user guide, so yes I believe the docker daemon is started. How can I double check?

Comment: `ps aux | grep docker` if docker is running you'll see it, or type `docker` and if it's running it'll show list of commands

Comment: Actually you found the solution. With boot2docker you will never need sudo with linux you would always need sudo. This is because boot2docker actually runs those commands in a virtual box which is setup to access the daemon correctly.

Comment: I was struggling with this issue and running without sudo worked for me

Comment: Almost all answers are **OS X specific** (they mention `boot2docker`) although OS X is not explicitly mentioned in the question or tags. If anyone is interested in generic answer please see my answer.

Comment: The last update is correct, works without `sudo`!

Answer (score 149):

For me, running `$(boot2docker shellinit 2> /dev/null)` fixed the problem.

This runs the output of the `boot2docker shellinit` command (the three `set -x ...` lines) in your current terminal session, which lets the `docker` command know where to find the boot2docker virtual machine.

Adding `$(boot2docker shellinit 2> /dev/null)` to the bottom of your `~/.bash_profile` file will make sure the `docker` command is configured, every time you open your terminal.

---

For people using Fish shell: `boot2docker shellinit ^ /dev/null | source`.

---

Note that `2> /dev/null` (and the Fish equivalent `^ /dev/null`) are optional. Like @pablo-fernandez suggested, this hides the `Writing ..` lines.

Comment: I had already done this, but I will add it to .bash_profile, good idea

Comment: definitely helps with boot2docker 1.5, but older one boot2docker 1.2 did not do it correctly

Comment: I added a stderr redirection so the "Writting..." statements dont appear: 
$(boot2docker shellinit 2> /dev/null)

Comment: Thank you to mention the fish shell! Solved the problem for me.

Comment: As mentioned in Salvador Dali's answer below, make sure you also run `boot2docker start` before running the shell init.

Answer (score 79):

I was getting the same error on MacOS with sudo and without it.

I have solved it with:

```
boot2docker start
$(boot2docker shellinit)
```

**P.S.:** Thanks to Alan. I found out that this approach is recommended in [their official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/installation/mac/).

**P.S.2:** Sometimes `boot2docker init` can be required before running two commands (thank you Aaron).

Comment: THis worked, but i don't understand why? what is the $(boot2docker shellinit) doing?

Comment: This worked in Mac OS X but I have the same question as Emile, i.e. why did this work?

Comment: This did not work for me on Mac OSX 10.10.4 with Docker Tools.

Comment: I had not only to run boot2docker shellinit, but also copy and run each of commands it displayed. Official documentation by the link says that this command only displays required set of commands

Comment: Worked for me as well on a windows machine.

Answer (score 55):

In my case (Linux Mint 17) I did various things, and I'm not sure about which of them are totally necessary.

I included missing Ubuntu packages:

```
$ sudo apt-get install apparmor lxc cgroup-lite
```

A user was added to group `docker`:

```
$ sudo usermod -aG docker ${USER}
```

**Started daemon** (openSUSE just needs this)

```
$ sudo docker -d
```

---

#### Thanks\Attribution

---

Thanks [Usman Ismail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/706727/usman-ismail), because maybe it was just that last thing...

> Stupid question but have you started the docker daemon? –  Usman Ismail Dec 17 '14 at 15:04

---

Thanks also to [github@MichaelJCole](https://github.com/MichaelJCole) for the solution that worked for me, because I didn't check for the daemon when I read Usman's comment.

[GitHub comment](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7494#issuecomment-66885741):

```
sudo apt-get install apparmor lxc cgroup-lite
sudo apt-get  install docker.io
# If you installed docker.io first, you'll have to start it manually
sudo docker -d
sudo docker run -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash
```

---

Thanks to [fredjean.net post](https://fredjean.net/running-docker-under-linux-mint-16/) for noticing the missing packages and forget about the default Ubuntu installation instructions and google about other ways

> It turns out that the cgroup-lite and the lxc packages are not installed by default on Linux Mint. Installing both then allowed me to run bash in the base image and then build and run my image.

---

Thanks to [brettof86](https://stackoverflow.com/users/903025/brettof86)'s comment about openSUSE

Comment: Thanks! In my case (Mint 17.1) it was the apparmor that was missing.

Comment: Adding myself to docker group did the thing for me, `sudo adduser $USER docker`. Trick to make it take effect on the current shell was `curgroup=$(id -gn) && newgrp docker && newgrp $curgroup`, adapted from http://superuser.com/questions/272061/reload-a-linux-users-group-assignments-without-logging-out

Comment: I guess the fact that this has a far lower score is because more people are using OS X than Linux? I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and it works for me.

Comment: openSUSE and I only needed to start the daemon

Comment: Excuse my ignorance about docker-machine, but i don't know.
But if you find out please point it out here in the comments or editing the answer. :D

Comment: I only needed to add myself to docker group - running LMDE

Comment: `docker.io` _recommends_ `apparmor` and `cgroup-lite` and only _suggests_ `lxc`, which more than suggests that none of these should be required to use docker. However, the default install script doesn't add any users to the `docker` group, so I'd think that was the only part of this answer that is mandatory.

Comment: After following your steps I was able to run `sudo docker run hello-world` but I still got several errors `ERRO[0037] Couldn't run auplink before unmount: exec: "auplink": executable file not found in $PATH`. After installing aufs-tools (`sudo apt-get install aufs-tools`) that error was gone, too.

Comment: @Malte, nice to hear that.

Could you tell me some more info on the machine you had the problems? That way we can add a disclaimer for that environment.

Here are some commands that would be helpful in retrieving that info (http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88647/165070) -->
| $ uname -a
| $ lsb_release -a
| $ cat /etc/lsb-release 
| $ cat /etc/issue.net
| $ cat /etc/debian_version

Answer (score 49):

The underlining problem is simple – lack of permission to `/var/run/docker.sock` unix domain socket.

From *Daemon socket option* [chapter](http://docs.docker.com/v1.6/reference/commandline/cli/#daemon-socket-option) of *Docker Command Line* reference for Docker 1.6.0:

> By default, a unix domain socket (or IPC socket) is created at
>   `/var/run/docker.sock`, **requiring either root permission, or docker
>   group membership**.

Steps necessary to grant rights to users are nicely described in Docker [installation instructions for Fedora](http://docs.docker.com/installation/fedora/#fedora-21-and-later-installation):

> Granting rights to users to use Docker
>
> The docker command line tool
>   contacts the docker daemon process via a socket file
>   `/var/run/docker.sock` owned by `root:root`. Though it's recommended to
>   use sudo for docker commands, if users wish to avoid it, an
>   administrator can create a docker group, have it own
>   `/var/run/docker.sock`, and add users to this group.
>
> `$ sudo groupadd docker`
>   `$ sudo chown root:docker /var/run/docker.sock`
>   `$ sudo usermod -a -G docker $USERNAME`

Log out and log back in for above changes to take effect.
Please note that Docker packages of some Linux distributions (Ubuntu) do already place `/var/run/docker.sock` in the `docker` group making the first two of above steps unnecessary.

In case of OS X and `boot2docker` the situation is different; the Docker daemon runs inside a VM so the `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable must be set to this VM so that the Docker client could find the Docker daemon. This is done by running `$(boot2docker shellinit)` in the shell.

Comment: Hmm, my situation is similar but subtly different.  I am running on Ubuntu 14.04.  Docker seemingly installed correctly (entering just "docker" brings up the list of commands).  I created a docker group and made my user a member of it.  This is just a home system and I'm just playing with docker.  However anything other than just "docker" brings up the error.  I believe it because docker cannot create /var/run/docker.sock.  On my system /var/run is a symlink to /run which is root:root and 755 perm so docker can't write there.  Not sure what my solution to this would be.

Comment: Piotr, this explanation is very useful. Canyou elaborate on why "$(boot2docker shellinit)" works, but plain "boot2docker shellinit" does not? I understand that the parentheses imply execution in a subshell, but I haven't been able to puzzle out why that's necessary to make docker work properly when none of the other commands require it....

Comment: @AlexEdelstein The difference between `boot2docker shellinit` and other commands is that this command does not make any changes itself but it only generates (prints) commands you have to run yourself. You could run `boot2docker shellinit` first and then manually copy and run each command from its output. It's easier to run all commands by running `boot2docker shellinit` in a subprocess (with `$()` syntax) because this way each line of output is being automatically run as a shell command. See https://docs.docker.com/installation/mac/#from-your-command-line where this is shown in detail.

Comment: @SteveCohen You might want to check that the docker service is running with `sudo service docker status`. On my Ubuntu 14.04 it was not running after installation, which caused the error.

Comment: Just trying docker @JavaOne, and I ran into this error on my Ubuntu 14.04 system, a quick `sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock' worked as a quick fix.

Comment: Thanks for linking the actual documentation for the root cause, solved my problem

Answer (score 23):

Make sure the Docker daemon is running:

```
service docker start
```

That fixed it for me!

Comment: `sudo service docker start` for me

Comment: `systemctl enable docker.service` and
`systemctl start docker.service`

For system.d linux users (Arch in my case)

Comment: `sudo service docker restart` for me

Answer (score 15):

1. Docker calls itself a self-sufficient runtime for Linux containers.
   In simple terms it acts both as server and client.
2. The `$ docker version` command query is internal to the Docker executable and not to the daemon/service running.
3. `$ docker images or $ docker ps or $ docker pull centos` are commands which send queries to the docker daemon/service running.
4. Docker by default supports TLS connections to its daemon/service.
5. Only if the user you are logged in as is part of user group `docker` or you have used `sudo` before the command, e.g. `$ sudo docker images`, does it not require TLS connectivity.

Visit Docker documentation page *[Protect the Docker daemon socket](https://docs.docker.com/articles/https/#secure-by-default)*.

Scroll a little to the top and find `warning section` for clarity.

Comment: Popular answers so far only apply to OS X whereas this one is much more general, explains the cause and allowed me to get it solved on GNU/Linux.

Comment: @laffuste your command will WIPE USER'S ADDITIONAL GROUPS. because of the missing "-a"

Comment: @PawelBarcik terrible mistake, thanks: `sudo usermod -a -G docker {username}`

Comment: How does this *answer* answer the question? What is the reason for the error? How to fix it? (I'm not on OS X so existing answers do not apply).

Answer (score 13):

You will need to do:

```
$boot2docker init
$boot2docker start
```

The following settings fixed the issue:

```
$export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:2376
$export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/{profileName}/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm
$export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
```

Comment: This command can also be used to set the environment variables (rather than doing it manually): `eval "$(boot2docker shellinit)"`

Answer (score 11):

It is possible that you do not have the permission to the file yet.
It happened to me after I add myself to `docker`group using

```
sudo gpasswd -a user docker
```

but not yet logout.

To resolve this, you can either re-login, or use
`sg docker "docker <subcommand> ..."` before you logout.

If you are in group `docker`  in `/etc/group`, you should be able to run it without typing password.

https://dingyichen.wordpress.com/2015/02/05/docker-dial-unix-varrundocker-sock-no-such-file-or-directory-are-you-trying-to-connect-to-a-tls-enabled-daemon-without-tls/

Answer (score 7):

On Ubuntu after installing **lxc-docker** you need to add your user to the **docker** user group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G docker myusername
```

This is because of the socket file permissions:

```
srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0 Mar 20 07:43 /var/run/docker.sock
```

**DO NOT RUN usermod WITHOUT "-a"** as suggested in one of the other comments or it will wipe your additional groups setting and will just leave the "docker" group

This is what will happen:

```
➜  ~  id pawel
uid=1000(pawel) gid=1000(pawel) groups=1000(pawel),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),108(lpadmin),124(sambashare),998(docker)
➜  ~  usermod -G docker pawel
➜  ~  id pawel               
uid=1000(pawel) gid=1000(pawel) groups=1000(pawel),998(docker)
```

Answer (score 6):

**TLDR**: This got my Python meetup group past this problem when I was running a clinic on installing docker and most of the users were on OS X:

```
boot2docker init
boot2docker up
```

run the `export` commands the output gives you, then

```
docker info
```

should tell you it works.

---

**The Context (what brought us to the problem)**

I led a clinic on installing docker and most attendees had OS X, and we ran into this problem and I overcame it on several machines. Here's the steps we followed:

First, we installed homebrew (yes, some attendees didn't have it):

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Then we got cask, which we used to install virtualbox, and then used brew to install docker and boot2docker (all required for OS X) [Don't use sudo for brew.](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/9953):

```
brew install caskroom/cask/brew-cask
brew cask install virtualbox
brew install docker
brew install boot2docker
```

**The Solution**

That was when we ran into the problem the asker here got. The following fixed it. I understand `init` was a one-time deal, but you'll probably have to run `up` every time you start docker:

```
boot2docker init
boot2docker up
```

Then when `up` has been run, it gives several `export` commands. Copy-paste and run those.

Finally `docker info` should tell you it's properly installed.

**To Demo**

The rest of the commands should demo it. (on Ubuntu linux I required sudo.)

```
docker run hello-world
docker run -it ubuntu bash
```

Then you should be on a root shell in the container:

```
apt-get install nano
exit
```

Back to your native user bash:

```
docker ps -l
```

Look for the about 12 digit hexadecimal (0-9 or a-f) identifier under "Container ID", e.g. `456789abcdef`. You can then commit your change and name it some descriptive name, like `descriptivename`:

```
docker commit 456789abcdef descriptivename`
```

Answer (score 5):

Everything that you need to run Docker on Linux Ubuntu/Mint:

```
sudo apt-get -y install lxc
sudo gpasswd -a ${USER} docker
newgrp docker
sudo service docker restart
```

Optionally, you may need to install two additional dependencies if the above doesn't work:

```
sudo apt-get -y install apparmor cgroup-lite
sudo service docker restart
```

Comment: I'd give myself +1 if it were possible - I was looking for a solution and found my own solution which I forgot about :)

Comment: This helped me. I realized that the docker service wasn't running after installation, so `sudo service docker start` solved the issue on my Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 3):

I tried the solutions here, and boot2docker didn't work.

**My solution:** Uninstall boot2docker on the Mac, install a Centos 7 VM in VirtualBox, and work with Docker inside that VM.

Answer (score 3):

For me the following steps worked:

1. I noticed that running `docker run hello-world` fails with this socked error as in the question, but running `sudo docker run hello-world` worked.
2. I added my current user to the `docker` group, `sudo adduser user docker`. Then you must restart your machine or use `su - user` (check using `groups` command if are in the `docker` group).

After that, `hello-world` started to work.

My answer is based on *[How can I use docker without sudo?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477551/how-can-i-use-docker-without-sudo)* which explains what go wrong.

---

Comment: After adding self to group, do `newgrp docker; newgrp primary-group this creates a subshell, with new primary group of docker, then re-establishes the correct primary group. (A bit of a hack).

Answer (score 2):

For what it is worth, I tried all the solutions in this question and in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27528337/1290420) and none resolved my issue until I uninstalled and re-installed [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/). This process upgraded the VirtualBox from version 4.2.16 to 4.3.22 (my previous one had been lying unused on the system for a few months).

Then `boot2docker` and `docker` worked without any other adjustments.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. A simple `service docker restart` solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The Docker daemon binds to a Unix socket instead of a TCP port. By default that Unix socket is owned by the user root and other users can only access it using sudo. The Docker daemon always runs as the root user.

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Log out and log back in so that your group membership is re-evaluated.

```
docker run hello-world
```

Source: [Manage Docker as a non-root user](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and tried various things to fix this, amending the .bash_profile file, logging in and out, without any luck. In the end, restarting my machine fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
```

in your

```
`/etc/hosts `
```

file.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when I was creating Docker images from Jenkins. Simply add the user to the `docker` group and then restart Docker services and in my case I had to restart Jenkins services.

This was the error which I got:

```
http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.19/build?cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=Dockerfile&memory=0&memswap=0&rm=1&t=59aec062a8dd8b579ee1b61b299e1d9d340a1340: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: permission denied. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
FATAL: Failed to build docker image from project Dockerfile
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to build docker image from project Dockerfile

Solution:

[root@Jenkins ssh]# groupadd docker
[root@Jenkins ssh]# gpasswd -a jenkins docker
Adding user jenkins to group docker
[root@Jenkins ssh]# /etc/init.d/docker restart
Stopping docker:                                           [  OK  ]
Starting docker:                                           [  OK  ]
[root@Jenkins ssh]# /etc/init.d/jenkins restart
Shutting down Jenkins                                      [  OK  ]
Starting Jenkins                                           [  OK  ]
[root@Jenkins ssh]#
```

Answer (score -1):

Another possible reason is that your **BIOS CPU visualization** is not enabled. Go and enable it first!