# OSX boot2docker hangs on "Waiting for VM and Docker daemon to start …"

Tags: boot2docker

I've installed `boot2docker` on `OSX 10.8.5` and it seems that the installation went fine, but when I try to launch `boot2docker` I get the following, which hangs indefinitely:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/boot2docker up 
Waiting for VM and Docker daemon to start...
..........................................................................oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
```

What steps should I take to debug this? I haven't been able to find any information on this particular issue.

```
$ boot2docker version
Boot2Docker-cli version: v1.4.1
Git commit: 43241cb

$ docker version
Client version: 1.4.1
Client API version: 1.16
Go version (client): go1.3.3
Git commit (client): 5bc2ff8
OS/Arch (client): darwin/amd64

$ boot2docker -v up
Boot2Docker-cli version: v1.4.1
Git commit: 43241cb
2014/12/23 00:19:25 executing: VBoxManage showvminfo boot2docker-vm --machinereadable
2014/12/23 00:19:25 executing: VBoxManage showvminfo boot2docker-vm --machinereadable
2014/12/23 00:19:25 executing: VBoxManage showvminfo boot2docker-vm --machinereadable
Waiting for VM and Docker daemon to start...
.Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).^C
```

---

In my `~/.bash_profile` file:

```
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:2376
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/Me/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
```

---

When I open `VirtualBox`, this what I see:

[image]

---

I've tried `powering off` and `removing` the `boot2docker-vm` using the `Virtual Box` GUI, and I get the following when I run `boot2docker` again:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/boot2docker init 
error in run: Failed to initialize machine "boot2docker-vm": exit status 2
```

And then:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/boot2docker up 
Waiting for VM and Docker daemon to start...
...............................................................…..
```

Which hangs endlessly.

---

**Additionally**

```
$ docker ps
FATA[0000] Couldn't read ca cert /Users/Me/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm/ca.pem: open /Users/Me/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm/ca.pem: no such file or directory
```

And:

```
$ sudo docker ps
FATA[0000] Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.16/containers/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
```

---

Following Sven's advice below deleted the `boot2docker-vm` again and run `init` in verbose mode:

```
    $ boot2docker -v init
Boot2Docker-cli version: v1.4.1
Git commit: 43241cb
2014/12/23 01:53:02 executing: VBoxManage showvminfo boot2docker-vm --machinereadable
2014/12/23 01:53:02 executing: VBoxManage showvminfo boot2docker-vm --machinereadable
2014/12/23 01:53:03 executing: VBoxManage list vms
2014/12/23 01:53:03 executing: VBoxManage createvm --name boot2docker-vm --register
Virtual machine 'boot2docker-vm' is created and registered.
UUID: eca00a0a-6d68-45f3-acd1-ccc4dd1bcec9
Settings file: '/Users/Me/VirtualBox VMs/boot2docker-vm/boot2docker-vm.vbox'
2014/12/23 01:53:03 executing: VBoxManage showvminfo boot2docker-vm --machinereadable
2014/12/23 01:53:03 executing: VBoxManage setextradata boot2docker-vm VBoxInternal/CPUM/EnableHVP 1
2014/12/23 01:53:03 executing: VBoxManage modifyvm boot2docker-vm --firmware bios --bioslogofadein off --bioslogofadeout off --bioslogodisplaytime 0 --biosbootmenu disabled --natdnshostresolver1 off --natdnsproxy1 off --ostype Linux26_64 --cpus 8 --memory 2048 --vram 8 --acpi on --ioapic on --rtcuseutc on --cpuhotplug off --pae on --longmode on --synthcpu off --hpet on --hwvirtex on --triplefaultreset off --nestedpaging on --largepages on --vtxvpid on --vtxux off --accelerate3d off --uart1 0x3F8 4 --uartmode1 server /Users/AJB/.boot2docker/boot2docker-vm.sock --boot1 dvd
2014/12/23 01:53:03 executing: VBoxManage showvminfo boot2docker-vm --machinereadable
2014/12/23 01:53:03 executing: VBoxManage modifyvm boot2docker-vm --nic1 nat --nictype1 virtio --cableconnected1 on
2014/12/23 01:53:03 executing: VBoxManage controlvm boot2docker-vm natpf1 ssh,tcp,127.0.0.1,2022,,22
2014/12/23 01:53:03 executing: VBoxManage list hostonlyifs
2014/12/23 01:53:03 executing: VBoxManage list dhcpservers
2014/12/23 01:53:03 executing: VBoxManage hostonlyif create
0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
2014/12/23 01:53:03 executing: VBoxManage hostonlyif ipconfig dyld: DYLD_ environment variables being ignored because main executable (/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxNetAdp --ip 192.168.59.3 --netmask 255.255.255.0
VBoxManage: error: The host network interface with the given name could not be found
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_INVALID_ARG (0x80070057), component Host, interface IHost, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "FindHostNetworkInterfaceByName(name.raw(), hif.asOutParam())" at line 218 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
VBoxManage: error: Could not find interface 'dyld: DYLD_ environment variables being ignored because main executable (/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxNetAdp'
error in run: Failed to initialize machine "boot2docker-vm": exit status 2
```

---

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I would say that `$ /usr/local/bin/boot2docker init 
error in run: Failed to initialize machine "boot2docker-vm": exit status 2` is an indication that the vm wasn't properly deleted by the virtualbox GUI. I would do that again, and then run `boot2docker -v init` to see the verbose output. This may point towards the problem.

Comment: you _really_ should not hard-code the DOCKER env vars into your .bashrc file - the vm's IP address can be changed by virtualbox at any time. Instead, have it run `$(boot2docker shellinit)`

Comment: Which should I have run `$(boot2docker shellinit)`?

Comment: your ~/.bash_profile?

Comment: Okay, added `$(boot2docker shellinit)` to my `.bash_profile`, attempted to `. .bash_profile` and got `error in run: Failed to get machine "boot2docker-vm": machine not exist`. Ran `boot2docker` from the tray icon again and it hung again. Killed `boot2docker up` and tried to `source` my `.bash_profile` again and now terminal is just hanging.

Comment: I would uninstall and re-install everything except I've already done that twice so I'm not sure what to try anymore.

Comment: oh. now this sounds familiar - https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/525#issuecomment-59047975 suggests that you need to delete the vm using the vbox GUI and then also delete the `/Users/<USER>/VirtualBox VMs/` dir.

Comment: There is also the possibility that the vbox host only networking settings are wrong (outside the vm itself). I'm not sure where in the menu's that is atm, i'm on my chromebox.

Comment: Network Adapter: `Attached to NAT`. Port forwarding: `Name: SSH, Protocol: TCP, Host IP: 127.0.0.1, Host Port: 2222, Guest IP: , Guest Port: 22`.  Well, that `2222` looks familiar. But what should it be set to?

Comment: Sorry, the above should read: That `2022` looks familiar.

Comment: I've determined that by changing the `Host Port` setting using the VBox GUI it will cause `boot2docker up -v` to attempt connection on the newly declared port, not the old `2022`. But what port should this be set to?

Comment: I notice the little preview screen in your VirtualBox manager says (in teeny tiny print), `"FATAL: Could not read from the boot medium! System halted."`  This fits with the actual VM image being bad, so deleting that VM image is a good idea. I've just run into this problem upon my very first setup using boot2docker. (And I'm actually still having trouble getting `boot2docker init` to complete making a new image...)

Answer (score 25):

I run into same problem on OSX Yosemite and have to do the following:

1) clean stuff with docker

- `boot2docker delete` -  ***Warning:*** this deletes all your docker images.
- In Virtualbox, go to VirtualBox (menu) =>
  Preferences => Network => Host Only Networks

  - Delete the host only networks, then I re-added them
- `boot2docker init`
- `boot2docker up`

2) very important, and you probabbly are missing it dealing with environmental variables, as they say:

```
To connect the Docker client to the Docker daemon, please set:
    export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:2376
    export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/andi/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm
    export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
```

For you the second export command will differ by user name - not `andi`, but something else. Just copy paste, and hit enter to apply this env variable, and then run e.g `docker ps` to check either thinks are working properly.

Answer (score 5):

Upgrading Virtual Box is the key but I did this before the upgrade to 4.3.26:

- Remove all from Virtual Box -> Preferences -> Network -> Host-only Networks
- Remove existing boot2docker-vm in Virtual Box
- Install the new version of Virtual Box
- Run boot2docker application

Comment: I experienced the same issue with VirtualBox 4.3.26. Deleting the `boot2docker-vm` fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

For what it is worth, I tried all the solutions in this question and in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27528337/1290420) and none resolved my issue until I uninstalled and re-installed [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/). This process upgraded the VirtualBox from version 4.2.16 to 4.3.22 (my previous one had been lying unused on the system for a few months).

Then `boot2docker` and `docker` worked without any other adjustments.

Comment: was it only the matter of fresh install, or the issue was connected with newer version installed later?

Comment: You are right @andi, the process upgraded VirtualBox

Comment: If you could state what was the culprit version it will be cool for others to know.

Comment: Done! I have also edited my answer to the other question for ease of reference (not sure if this is good practice)

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem. It was cisco anyconnect vpn client which messed everything up for me.
I found out from the internet that the simplest possible way of fixing this would be:

```
boot2docker stop
vboxmanage modifyvm "boot2docker-vm" --natpf1 "docker,tcp,127.0.0.1,2376,,2376"
boot2docker up
$(boot2docker shellinit)
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://127.0.0.1:2376
```

Starting from this point everything worked just fine even after restarting vpn client.