# Unable to start boot2docker in Windows7

Tags: boot2docker

I just installed boot2docker in Windows 7 but nothing happened! The first time was using the Boot2Docker start icon - it did the initializing part and then the window just closed. Then to investigate further I tried the `boot2docker -v up` command and the result is listed below.

```
C:\Program Files>boot2docker -v up
Boot2Docker-cli version: v1.6.0
Git commit: 9894ae9

2015/04/28 00:08:45 executing: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe
 showvminfo boot2docker-vm --machinereadable

2015/04/28 00:08:46 executing: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe
 guestproperty set boot2docker-vm /VirtualBox/GuestAdd/SharedFolders/MountPrefix
 /

2015/04/28 00:08:46 executing: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe
 guestproperty set boot2docker-vm /VirtualBox/GuestAdd/SharedFolders/MountDir /

2015/04/28 00:08:46 executing: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe
 sharedfolder add boot2docker-vm --name c/Users --hostpath C:\Users --automount
VBoxManage.exe: error: Shared folder named 'c/Users' already exists

VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_IN_USE (0x80bb000c), componen
t SessionMachine, interface IMachine, callee IUnknown

VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "CreateSharedFolder(Bstr(name).raw(), Bstr(hostp
ath).raw(), fWritable, fAutoMount)" at line 1008 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp

2015/04/28 00:08:46 executing: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe
 setextradata boot2docker-vm VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/c/U
sers 1

2015/04/28 00:08:46 executing: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe
 startvm boot2docker-vm --type headless

Waiting for VM "boot2docker-vm" to power on...
VM "boot2docker-vm" has been successfully started.

error in run: Failed to start machine "boot2docker-vm": exit status 1
```

What does this mean? I did an uninstall and reinstall and removed the boot2docker-vm and ran the `boot2docker init` and `boot2docker start` from the command prompt during the second attempt but same result.

Comment: Did you tried with the latest VirtualBox and the latest `Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack`, as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/29303930/6309?  See also https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/657.

Comment: You might try "boot2docker delete" to see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and tried the advice from above:

> You might try "boot2docker delete" to see if that helps. –  e40 Jul 17 at 16:43

But it wasn't enough on it's own.  I ended up redoing the steps several times, finally I tried starting the docker VM via the virtualbox gui and got a helpful message (with some googling it became helpful) warning me that hardware virtualization features (VM-X) might be disabled in my bios.

I enabled hardware virtualization features in my bios, and tried again.

I found that I could not just run boot2docker up or boot2docker start; I had to use start.sh itself.

Comment: Failed to mention: I changed the settig to enable hardware virtualization in my BIOS.My second issue was similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27614056/osx-boot2docker-hangs-on-waiting-for-vm-and-docker-daemon-to-start/28170951#28170951

Instead of using boot2docker up, I used start.sh.