# boot2docker - Waiting for VM and Docker daemon to start

Tags: boot2docker

I installed boot2docker on my Windows machine. When I start it in the command prompt using "boot2docker up -v" it never starts and this is the output:

```
Waiting for VM and Docker daemon to start...
*THE FOLLOWING REPEATED MILLION TIMES*
.Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0)

VM Host-only IP address:
Waiting for Docker daemon to start...

*THE FOLLOWING REPEATED MILLION TIMES*
executing: C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSSH\bin\ssh.exe ssh -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o LogLevel=quiet -p 2022 -i C:\Users\Enlightment\.ssh\id_boot2docker docker@localhost grep tcp:// /proc/$(cat /var/run/docker.pid)/cmdline
Error requesting socket: exit status 255
```

I have no idea what to do to start it... 
I know that there is the same topic already but it doesn't contain the solution. I deleted and initialized and started boot2docker multiple times and it doesn't change anything.

The Virtual Box is the latest version - 4.3.28.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it was not what I expected but I found out what's the reason behind the error. CPU Virtualization (VT-x) was not present.

Comment: I have the same issue , can you elaborate a little bit your answer ?  I run sysctl -a | grep machdep.cpu.features and I can see VMX ...

Comment: My issue was the old CPU with no virtualization, but yours is probably answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27614056/osx-boot2docker-hangs-on-waiting-for-vm-and-docker-daemon-to-start).