# Docker TLS error on Mac

Tags: docker

I ran `docker images` and got the following error:

```
FATA[0000] Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.17/images/json:
dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory.
Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
```

There seems to be no useful message on how to fix the error. What could be wrong?

Comment: The Docker daemon isn't running.

Comment: Take a look at this question: [Am I trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27528337/am-i-trying-to-connect-to-a-tls-enabled-daemon-without-tls)

Comment: Oh; I am using docker on mac and starting docker is really confusing. When I type `docker` it shows me the help, so I thought it was running.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

https://docs.docker.com/installation/mac/

you need to do this *once*:

```
boot2docker init
```

then, everytime you reboot your mac you will need to run :

```
boot2docker start
```

That is the command that starts the docker daemon.  But, on each shell you want to access it from you will need to run:

```
$(boot2docker shellinit)
```

Now you can use the docker client, like:

```
docker run hello-world
```

Comment: I think we need to `boot2docker ssh` as well? Because docker run hello-world still does not run on my mac (Same TLS error). When I sshed and ran docker search, it worked pretty well.

Comment: hmmm.  i ran these commands on my mac and they worked. you *must* run $(boot2docker shellinit) after you init and start docker.  When I skip that step I get the TLS error.  If you run boot2docker without the leading $( and the trailing ) it won't work.  Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Oh I ran it without the $(..) so maybe it didn't work earlier. I used `eval "$(boot2docker shellinit)"` as it was in the docs and it worked. I don't have to use `boot2docker ssh` now before.

Answer (score 3):

Your docker daemon is simply not running.

Just run `service docker start`

Comment: My mac does not have `service`. How do I start docker easily?

Comment: Figured out `/usr/local/bin/boot2docker up` seems to do the job on Mac. (Boot2Docker app is required). This helped me: https://docs.docker.com/installation/mac/

Comment: Sorry I thought you were on Linux! Indeed, for mac you have to use boot2docker

Answer (score 0):

It may be not a bug. I am facing the same log when run :"boot2docker up -v" command. Then 'eval "$(boot2docker shellinit)" '  just doesn't work on fish but the "boot2docker shellinit" is actually the fish command. Then I switch to zsh, there is some wired output which also has been reported somewhere. Then I switch to bash. I try both 'eval "$(boot2docker shellinit)" ' and "$(boot2docker shellinit)" without eval. Then I found that "boot2docker shellinit" also generates the fish script. Which may give me the answer why it doesn't work at first place. So I copied the three line of fish script and pasted it in the fish shell and now the error log the one you are facing is going even in the bash. I don't really know the reason. Usually the ev on works on the current shell and current session.