# Can't install docker properly

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ubuntu-12.04

Installed docker1.6 from deb package but have a problem on running:

sudo docker version
Client version: 1.6.2
Client API version: 1.18
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 7c8fca2
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
FATA[0000] Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.18/version: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?

Any ideas how to fix or debug it?

I didn't have external net on that machine so I downloaded docker deb by this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
docker_version=1.6.1
get_docker=https://get.docker.io/ubuntu/pool/main/l

for package in lxc-docker lxc-docker-$docker_version; do
    deb=${package}_${docker_version}_amd64.deb
    curl -s $get_docker/$package/$deb -o $deb
done
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming. Try http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: There are tons of similar("not about programming") questions on stackoverflow, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27528337/am-i-trying-to-connect-to-a-tls-enabled-daemon-without-tls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means the Docker daemon isn't running. Try running `docker -d` first, then running your Docker command.

If that returns an error, you'll need to figure out why (you may be missing a dependency for example).

Answer (score 0):

can you try this command:

`sudo wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/ | sh`

Comment: I don't have external net on that server.